Extracting data from a Node network
Good day all.
I have the attached network (see image attached). There is a network of Blue nodes (numbered) and a network of Green nodes (also numbered). Now both sets of nodes are defined (in terms of number of node and x-y coordinates) in JSON files.
`Blue nodes``
[
{
"name": 0,
"x": 30,
"y": 24
},
{
"name": 1,
"x": 305,
"y": 26
},
{
"name": 2,
"x": 584,
"y": 25
},
{
"name": 3,
"x": 589,
"y": 308
},
{
"name": 4,
"x": 584,
"y": 585
},
{
"name": 5,
"x": 307,
"y": 587
},
{
"name": 6,
"x": 29,
"y": 584
},
{
"name": 7,
"x": 29,
"y": 309
},
{
"name": 8,
"x": 306,
"y": 307
}
]
Green nodes
[
{
"name": 0,
"x": 105,
"y": 9
},
{
"name": 1,
"x": 230,
"y": 36
},
{
"name": 2,
"x": 390,
"y": 13
},
{
"name": 3,
"x": 501,
"y": 34
},
{
"name": 4,
"x": 596,
"y": 89
},
{
"name": 5,
"x": 572,
"y": 223
},
{
"name": 6,
"x": 600,
"y": 348
},
{
"name": 7,
"x": 577,
"y": 468
},
{
"name": 8,
"x": 513,
"y": 593
},
{
"name": 9,
"x": 360,
"y": 570
},
{
"name": 10,
"x": 233,
"y": 590
},
{
"name": 11,
"x": 99,
"y": 569
},
{
"name": 12,
"x": 12,
"y": 508
},
{
"name": 13,
"x": 36,
"y": 386
},
{
"name": 14,
"x": 18,
"y": 228
},
{
"name": 15,
"x": 35,
"y": 102
},
{
"name": 16,
"x": 115,
"y": 295
},
{
"name": 17,
"x": 225,
"y": 314
},
{
"name": 18,
"x": 295,
"y": 232
},
{
"name": 19,
"x": 316,
"y": 99
},
{
"name": 20,
"x": 381,
"y": 296
},
{
"name": 21,
"x": 507,
"y": 313
},
{
"name": 22,
"x": 317,
"y": 374
},
{
"name": 23,
"x": 295,
"y": 504
}
]
As can be seen, from the image, certain Green nodes appear between certain pairs of Blue nodes. For example, Green nodes 2 and 3 appear between Blue nodes 1 and 2. What I need to do is to "scan" through the data to identify these associations of Green nodes with pairs of Blue nodes. With a small network one can do this visually. However, with a larger network it becomes tedious and prone to error. I am looking for a way of using code to achieve this? No idea what might work? Perhaps if I could move a "target" between pairs of Blue nodes looking, as I move, for "collisions" with Green nodes. Unless there is an easier way. Hope this is clear and sorry for the length of this post.
Paul



I have tried looping through both the Green nodes and Blue nodes (in nested loops) checking if the x component of a particular Green node was less than, or greater than the x coordinate of a given Blue node and then checking the y coordinates, but this did not lead to a solution.


This all depends on how large the network will be, and more precisely how we define green nodes being between blue ones. I'll assume you mean between as described in the below photo (nodes within the lines which start from pairs of blue nodes, perpendicular to the line between them)

You can compute this for all possible sets of blue points, (b1, b2) pairwise as the vectors orthogonal to the vector which goes through b1 and b2, these vectors going through b1 and b2 respectively.
This can be computed pairwise for each possible pair of blue nodes, giving a list of possible regions, defined by two straight, parallel lines.
Then, for each green node, you just need to plug the coordinates for the green node in - if the value for one line is positive and the other is negative, the green node lies between the lines.
This is pretty simple for smaller networks, but if it were for thousands of nodes, the computational complexity will ramp up quickly

Thank you Hugh.  I will give that a go.   Paul
